# How to append multiple occurrences of a letter from a string?

Tags: python

I am trying to append multiple occurrences of a string into a list as so:

index('Mississippi', 's')
[2,3,5,6]

s is found at index 2,3,5 and 6.

It's a very simple code, yet I'm not sure why mine isn't working ?

Python

```
def index(w,l):

    wo=[]

    for i in range(len(w)):
        if w[i] == l:
            wor= w.find(l)
            wo.append(wor)
    return(wo)
```

It only returns [2,2,2,2] when it should return [2,3,5,6] !

Thanks!

Comment: Print out `wor`. It is `2`. Why is this? Must be because `w.find(l)` is giving 2. Why is this? See documentation! https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find "Return the lowest index in the string where substring sub is found..."

Comment: So you want to input a word, like Mississippi and add the indices of the letter 's' into a list named 'wo'?

Comment: yes ! it's not rocket science

Answer (score 2):

`w.find()` always returns the index of the first match, so you can't use it when there are duplicates. Append the current index of the iteration, which is `i`. So change `mo.append(wor)` to `mo.append(i)`.

The whole thing can be done in a single list comprehension.

```
def index(w, l):
    return [i for i, c in enumerate(w) if c == l]
```

Comment: Is there a way you could modify my code and keep the simplicity ?

Comment: @Mr.Green Convert it to `for ...: if ...: wo.append(i)`

Comment: @MateenUlhaq , I owe you a left kidney, thank you ! I got it now

Comment: Nothing more satisfying than this, instead of copying code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find()` with `while`

```
def findall(f, s):
    wo = []
    i = -1
    while True:
        i = s.find(f, i+1)
        if i == -1:
            return wo
        wo.append(s.find(f, i))

findall('s','Mississippi')
[2, 3, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is not the best, but it would be good to know the following:

```
import re

wo = [m.span()[0] for m in re.finditer('s', w)]
```

You can find all matches of a given pattern with `finditer` in the regular expression library.